# Convert Ruby expression to Arel

Tags: ruby, activerecord, arel

I have an expression that picks the top three reviews by the number of stars the current user has given them

```
@event.reviews.sort_by { |r| -r.stars.select{ |s| s.user_id == current_user.id }.count }.first(3)
```

The problem is that it pulls all the reviews and stars into memory and does this in Ruby. Short of doing this in straight SQL, is there a way to achieve same thing in arel so that the database does the bulk of the computation instead of Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following, `counter` here represents the number of `stars` from `current_user` for a `review`

```
# Single query with inner join
@event.reviews.joins(:stars)
       .select("reviews.*, stars.id ,SUM(stars.user_id = #{current_user.id}) AS counter ")
       .group("reviews.id ")
       .order("counter DESC").limit(3)
```

The above sql query would create a inner join table of `reviews` and `stars`.

Depending on the size of these tables, it might be faster to eager load `reviews` and `stars` for the event when you are fetching `@event`. For e.g.

```
 # Eager loading with separate queries
 @event =  Event.find(params[:id]).includes(:reviews => :stars)
```

The above method would make a single query to get all the stars for all the reviews associated with the event.

If you are using `stars` and `reviews` in other places in the same request, then it is better to eager load them with `includes`.